# server.mappath issue

Tags: .net, asp.net

I have this variable that holds a path.

I want to see the result for MapPath using this variable, but I get this error. Any Idea?

```
string FolderName = "Docs/1/1232"
'Server.MapPath(FolderName)' threw an exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException'
```

Stack trace:

> at System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.GetPhysicalPathForPath(String path, VirtualDirectoryMapping mapping)
>      at System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.GetPathConfigFilename(String siteID, VirtualPath path, String& directory, String& baseName)
>      at System.Web.Configuration.UserMapPath.MapPath(String siteID, String path)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathInternal(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>      at System.Web.VirtualPath.MapPathInternal()
>      at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping)
>      at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath)
>      at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path)
>      at FileUpload.CreateFolder(String FolderName) in c:\Projects\WebSites\MyShul\FileUpload.aspx.cs:line 186
>      at FileUpload.UploadFile() in c:\Projects\WebSites\MyShul\FileUpload.aspx.cs:line 53
>      at FileUpload.btnUpload_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Projects\WebSites\MyShul\FileUpload.aspx.cs:line 236
>      at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
>      at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>      at System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>      at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)

Comment: Can you post the stack trace? Is there a `Docs/1/1232` folder relative to the calling page?

Comment: @user181421 - please _edit_ the question and put the stack trace in it and delete the comments.

Comment: @user181421 - Can you also post the exception _message_, not just the type?

Comment: Failed to map the path '/MyShul/Docs/1 /28/'.

Comment: @user181421 - Looks like that directory does not exist. Is there indeed a `/MyShul/Docs/1 /28/` folder at the root of the virtual application? Note that you have a _space_ after the `1` in your error.

Comment: AAAAAAhhhhhh....MAN! I didn't see this space. I removed it, and it worked like a dream. I appreciate your help Oded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The path you are trying to map does not exist in the virtual directory.

Make sure you are using a correct path (for your example, probably the *space* is wrong).